# On inserting to a database with predefined value C#

Tags: c#, string, textbox

OK I have a text box with a set value, I only want this set value sent if the text box is not filled in on completion of form.

**code**

```
dontaion_euro.Text = "99.00";
```

problem is when I click `send` it only sends the data `99.00` I only want this sent if blank.
how could I achieve this?

Comment: ASP, winforms or WPF?

Comment: Why your setting the value to same textbox which is used to check null or empty?

Comment: due to I have other text boxes and this one needs to add 99 even if left empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step1 :** you need to `Trim` the `Textbox` value to remove the `white spaces`.

**Step2 :** you can `compare` the `Textbox` value with `Empty String` to check whether `Textbox` value is `Empty` or not

Try this:

```
if(donation_euro.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
{
donation_euro.Text="99.00";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) method like;

> Indicates whether the specified string is null or an Empty string.

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(dontaion_euro.Text))
{
  dontaion_euro.Text = "99.00";
}
else
{ 
  //Your textbox is not null or empty
}
```